# Curious Badge bar should display something useful even when main criterion is fulfilled

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page, badge-progress

This is the current progress towards the [Curious badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/242/curious), as appears in [my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/281760/?tab=topactivity):

> [image]

The curious, inquisitive, and socratic badge requires two conditions of completion to earn it.
The visual representation of it seems like it is only showing me one of the parameters of completion, and when clicking it does mention the other criterion isn't yet fulfilled:

> [image]

Can the bar be somehow divided up so that it shows both at the same time?

I would imagine it like:

> [image: pic]

**EDIT:** Now it seems even buggier. Here's what I see:

> [image: pic]

Comment: @PythonMaster Please point out to me which question that might be. I've never seen a request to split up the graphical user interface of the badge bar.

Comment: Improved the screenshots a bit. I agree it can be nice to see the progress towards "positive score" i.e. how many of the 5 eligible questions got positive score. That said, not sure it's worth the time, but leaving this up to the team.

Comment: Never mind that

Comment: Regarding the edit, why buggier? It just means you now have asked a well-received questions on 6 separate days, but still need to maintain positive score. Don't think the 6/5 is a bug on its own.

Answer (score 3):

I agree as it is quite weird to see the bar full but the second requirement hasn't been met.

I feel like instead of having two separate bars, each requirement would be half of the bar. What I mean by that is that one-half of the bat will be filled for asking on five plus days and the other half by having a positive score. To know how close you are to the second criteria, there should be a second number shown, which is the difference between the user's current score and 0.5, the current limit to get the Curious badge or any of its successors (the silver and gold badge) according to this formula:

> (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5

It could also be shown as a fraction type thing:

> {insert user's score}/0.5

The formula would be included to make sure users understand what the numbers mean.